# Padding between two jquery datepicker tables

Tags: html, css, datepicker

[image: Datepicker Example]

I need spacing between the two tables inside the jquery date picker which as common header.I tried with various solutions like giving padding to the parent div,but I"m unable to resolve it.Can anyone help?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
  .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
  .ui-button,
  html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover,
  html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
    background: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    color: #9c9c9c !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center !important;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  <!-- .ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled {
    border: 0 !important;
  }
  
  -->.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-default {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #FBD2D3 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:hover *,
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td>.ui-state-default.ui-state-hover,
  .ui-datepicker-current-day {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  thead::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-today {
    background-color: none !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker td span,
  .ui-datepicker td a {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  tbody {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
  
  td {
    border: 1px solid #F6F6F6 !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div {
    display: none;
    left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    width: 50% !important;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-header.ui-widget-header {
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #9c9c9c !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker th {
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .lowTicketValue {
    color: #326EA6;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .lowTicketValue:active {
    color: #fff !important;
    white-space: no-wrap;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-calendar .highlight {
    background-color: #FBD2D3 !important;
  }
  
  .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  .highTicketValue {
    color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1)>span {
    color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1):active>span,
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1):hover>span {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
</style>
<input type="text" id="flexibledates" />
<input type="text" id="flightdeparture" />
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#flexibledates').datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: 'D, d MM',
      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        insertMessageStartDate();
      },
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var selectedDate = $("#flexibledates").datepicker("getDate");
        if (selectedDate != null) {
          $('#flightdeparture').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
        }
      }
    });
    $('#flightdeparture').datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: 'D, d MM',

      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        insertMessageEndDate();
      },
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#flexibledates').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); // Reset maximum date     
      }



    });


    function insertMessageStartDate(message) {
      clearTimeout(insertMessageStartDate.timer);

      if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').is(':visible')) {
        $('.ui-state-default').after('<span class="lowTicketValue">' + 45555 + '</span>');



      } else
        insertMessageStartDate.timer = setTimeout(insertMessageStartDate, 10);
    }

    function insertMessageEndDate(message) {
      clearTimeout(insertMessageEndDate.timer);
      // $("#flexibledates").datepicker("getDate").css({"background-color": "#F4777C !important", "color": "#fff !important"});
      if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').is(':visible')) {

        $('.ui-state-default').after('<span class="lowTicketValue">' + 45555 + '</span>');
        $("#ui-datepicker-div td").on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div td").removeClass("highlight");
          }
        });


      } else
        insertMessageEndDate.timer = setTimeout(insertMessageEndDate, 10);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not an answer but the amount you're using `!important` in your css screams that you have a lot of problems elsewhere, which you might want to fix first

Comment: But, its taking some of the default jquery date picker css.So,I used !important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add css:

```
.ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
```

I'm overriding jquery-ui css here but notice I don't need `important`

Check the snippet out in full screen mode

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
  .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
  .ui-button,
  html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover,
  html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
    background: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    color: #9c9c9c !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center !important;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
  
  .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  <!-- .ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled {
    border: 0 !important;
  }
  
  -->.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-default {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #FBD2D3 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:hover *,
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td>.ui-state-default.ui-state-hover,
  .ui-datepicker-current-day {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  thead::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-today {
    background-color: none !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker td span,
  .ui-datepicker td a {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  tbody {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
  
  td {
    border: 1px solid #F6F6F6 !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div {
    display: none;
    left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    width: 50% !important;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-header.ui-widget-header {
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #9c9c9c !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker th {
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .lowTicketValue {
    color: #326EA6;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .lowTicketValue:active {
    color: #fff !important;
    white-space: no-wrap;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-calendar .highlight {
    background-color: #FBD2D3 !important;
  }
  
  .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  .highTicketValue {
    color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1)>span {
    color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1):active>span,
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1):hover>span {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
</style>
<input type="text" id="flexibledates" />
<input type="text" id="flightdeparture" />
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#flexibledates').datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: 'D, d MM',
      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        insertMessageStartDate();
      },
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var selectedDate = $("#flexibledates").datepicker("getDate");
        if (selectedDate != null) {
          $('#flightdeparture').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
        }
      }
    });
    $('#flightdeparture').datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: 'D, d MM',

      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        insertMessageEndDate();
      },
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#flexibledates').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); // Reset maximum date     
      }



    });


    function insertMessageStartDate(message) {
      clearTimeout(insertMessageStartDate.timer);

      if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').is(':visible')) {
        $('.ui-state-default').after('<span class="lowTicketValue">' + 45555 + '</span>');



      } else
        insertMessageStartDate.timer = setTimeout(insertMessageStartDate, 10);
    }

    function insertMessageEndDate(message) {
      clearTimeout(insertMessageEndDate.timer);
      // $("#flexibledates").datepicker("getDate").css({"background-color": "#F4777C !important", "color": "#fff !important"});
      if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').is(':visible')) {

        $('.ui-state-default').after('<span class="lowTicketValue">' + 45555 + '</span>');
        $("#ui-datepicker-div td").on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div td").removeClass("highlight");
          }
        });


      } else
        insertMessageEndDate.timer = setTimeout(insertMessageEndDate, 10);
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Update** - I don't think you can do exactly what you want but you can make a change like so, again, have a look full screen:

```
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
    width: 96%; /* <!-- !important NOT needed */
    margin: 4%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
  .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
  .ui-button,
  html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover,
  html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
    background: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    color: #9c9c9c !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center !important;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 2%;
  }
  
  <!-- .ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled {
    border: 0 !important;
  }
  
  -->.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-default {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #FBD2D3 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:hover *,
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td>.ui-state-default.ui-state-hover,
  .ui-datepicker-current-day {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  thead::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-today {
    background-color: none !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker td span,
  .ui-datepicker td a {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  
  tbody {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
  
  td {
    border: 1px solid #F6F6F6 !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div {
    display: none;
    left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    width: 50% !important;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-header.ui-widget-header {
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #9c9c9c !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker th {
    background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .lowTicketValue {
    color: #326EA6;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .lowTicketValue:active {
    color: #fff !important;
    white-space: no-wrap;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  .ui-datepicker-calendar .highlight {
    background-color: #FBD2D3 !important;
  }
  
  .ui-state-range {
    background-color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  .highTicketValue {
    color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1)>span {
    color: #F4777C !important;
  }
  
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1):active>span,
  #ui-datepicker-div tr td:nth-child(2n+1):hover>span {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
</style>
<input type="text" id="flexibledates" />
<input type="text" id="flightdeparture" />
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#flexibledates').datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: 'D, d MM',
      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        insertMessageStartDate();
      },
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var selectedDate = $("#flexibledates").datepicker("getDate");
        if (selectedDate != null) {
          $('#flightdeparture').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
        }
      }
    });
    $('#flightdeparture').datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: 'D, d MM',

      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        insertMessageEndDate();
      },
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#flexibledates').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate')); // Reset maximum date     
      }



    });


    function insertMessageStartDate(message) {
      clearTimeout(insertMessageStartDate.timer);

      if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').is(':visible')) {
        $('.ui-state-default').after('<span class="lowTicketValue">' + 45555 + '</span>');



      } else
        insertMessageStartDate.timer = setTimeout(insertMessageStartDate, 10);
    }

    function insertMessageEndDate(message) {
      clearTimeout(insertMessageEndDate.timer);
      // $("#flexibledates").datepicker("getDate").css({"background-color": "#F4777C !important", "color": "#fff !important"});
      if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').is(':visible')) {

        $('.ui-state-default').after('<span class="lowTicketValue">' + 45555 + '</span>');
        $("#ui-datepicker-div td").on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div td").removeClass("highlight");
          }
        });


      } else
        insertMessageEndDate.timer = setTimeout(insertMessageEndDate, 10);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Darren,The problem is I dont need any spacing between the days one(sunday,monday) between two tables.

Comment: Did you look at it "Full page"? (link on the right of "Run code snippet" buttons) There is now spacing between the tables

Comment: Yeah Darren,I looked at it.I'll explain it further,the months and days should have same background color without any padding,where as the dates(1,2,) should have padding left and right between two tables.The problem here is I wrote padding for tbody,it aint takes the value.Did you understand now?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't understand - can you create an image showing what you need?

Comment: Are you able to see the img in the question?

Comment: Updated answer with another example, I think the only way you'll achieve what you want is to put the dates in another table inside a table cell which will probably decouple them from the plug-in, not sure

Comment: Yea,That's why I'm also confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149485/discussion-between-hema-nandagopal-and-darren-sweeney).

Comment: No problem.I got a fix for it,I used background:linear gradient and fixed it :).Thanks for your help.